# java Serialization :- Program gets terminated at time of writeObject() method

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization

I start to learn java Serialization. I wrote a simple program where I send choice and the object from the client program. The choice is getting pass successfully but the program gets terminated as soon as it reaches writeObject() method.

please help!.
This is client side:-

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class client implements Serializable
{

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@SuppressWarnings("resource")
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException, Exception
{
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    Socket s=new Socket("127.0.0.1",9339);
    System.out.println("Connection successful");

    //to get input from keyboard
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);


    ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());

    int ch1,ch2;
    int choice;
    try
    {
        do
        {
            System.out.println("Enter your Choice :" );
            System.out.println("1.Add Student"+System.lineSeparator()+"2.Show Student");
            System.out.println("3.search Student"+System.lineSeparator()+"4.update Student");
            System.out.println("5.delete Student"+System.lineSeparator()+"6.Show fail Student");
            choice=sc.nextInt();
            out.writeInt(choice);
            switch(choice)
            {
            case 1:
            {
                do
                {
                    student stud=new student();
                    System.out.println("Enter Roll no. of Student : ");
                    stud.roll=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
                    System.out.println("Enter name of Student : ");
                    stud.name=br.readLine();
                    System.out.println("Enter Percentage : " );
                    stud.percent=sc.nextFloat();
                    System.out.println("Enter Attendance : ");
                    stud.attendance=sc.nextInt();
                    System.out.println("Enter Password of Student : ");
                    stud.pass=br.readLine();
                    out.writeObject(stud);
                    System.out.println("in Client Object is pass");

                    System.out.println("Do you want to add more (1.Yes/0.No)");
                    ch2=sc.nextInt();
                }while(ch2==1);
            }
            break;
            case 2:
            {

            }
            break;
            case 3:
            {

            }
            break;
            case 4:
            {

            }
            break;
            case 5:
            {

            }
            break;
            case 6:
            {

            }
            break;
            default :
                System.out.println("Error : Invalid Choice !!");
            }
            System.out.println("Do you want to Continue (1.Yes/0.No)");
            ch1=sc.nextInt();
        }while(ch1==1);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {

    }

}
}
```

this is Server side:-

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.*;


public class server  implements Serializable
{
/**
 * 
 */
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
   Enumeration <student> stud;
   Scanner sc =new Scanner(System.in);
   BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new 
InputStreamReader(System.in));
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public static Vector <student> arr=new <student> Vector<student>();


public void addStudent(student obj) throws NumberFormatException, IOException
{
    System.out.println("Enter Roll no. of Student : ");
    obj.roll=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    System.out.println("Enter name of Student : ");
    obj.name=br.readLine();
    System.out.println("Enter Percentage : " );
    obj.percent=sc.nextFloat();
    System.out.println("Enter Attendance : ");
    obj.attendance=sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter Password of Student : ");
    obj.pass=br.readLine();
}

public void showAttend(student obj)
{
    System.out.println("Attendance : "+obj.attendance);             
}
public void showPercent(student obj)
{
    System.out.println("Attendance : "+obj.percent);        
}


public void showStudent(student obj)
 {
     System.out.println("Student rollno : "+obj.roll);
     System.out.println("Student name : "+obj.name);
     System.out.println("Student Percentage : "+obj.percent);
     System.out.println("Student Attendance : "+obj.attendance);
 }
public void Display() //using itreator
{
    Iterator <student> itr= arr.iterator(); 
    while(itr.hasNext())
    {
        System.out.println(itr.next().toString());
    }
}
public void Show_Enumeration()
{
    stud=arr.elements();
    while(stud.hasMoreElements())
    {
        System.out.println(stud.nextElement().toString());
    }

}
public void fail(student obj)
{

    if(obj.percent<35)
    {
         this.showStudent(obj);
    }
}
public void update() throws NumberFormatException, IOException
{
    int temp;
    System.out.println("Enter rollno of Student to update ");
    temp=sc.nextInt();
    int index=search(temp);
    if(index!=-1)
    {
        arr.remove(index);
        System.out.println("Ente new updated Data : ");
        student obj=new student();
        arr.add(obj);
    }
}
public void delete()
{
    int temp;
    System.out.println("Enter rollno of Student to delete ");
    temp=sc.nextInt();
    int index=search(temp);
    if(index!=-1)
    {
        arr.remove(index);
        System.out.println("Student deleted succesfully: ");
    }
}
public <T> int search(T temp)
{
    int flag=0,index=-1;
    Integer r;
    String n;
    if(temp instanceof Integer)
    {
        r=(Integer)temp;
        for(student obj: arr)
        {
            if(obj.roll==r)
            {
                flag=1;
                index=arr.indexOf(obj);
                break;
            }

        }
        if(flag==1)
        {
            System.out.println("Record found Succefull ! ");

            return index;
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Record not found !");
            return -1;
        }
    }

    if(temp instanceof String)
    {
        n=(String) temp;
        for(student obj: arr)
        {
            if(obj.name.equalsIgnoreCase(n))
            {
                flag=1;
                index=arr.indexOf(obj);
                break;
            }

        }
        if(flag==1)
        {
            System.out.println("Record found Succefull ! ");

            return index;
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Record not found !");
            return -1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}


public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
{
    ServerSocket ss=new ServerSocket(9339);
    Socket s=ss.accept();

    // to read from keyboard
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader (System.in));


    ObjectInputStream in=new ObjectInputStream(s.getInputStream());

    int choice;
    server t=new server();
    try
    {
                    choice=in.readInt();
                    System.out.println("Choice in techer is"+choice);
                    switch(choice)
                    {
                    case 1:
                        {
                            student stud;
                            stud=(student)in.readObject();
                            arr.add(stud);
                        }
                        break;
                    case 2:
                    {
                        t.Display();// using iterator
                        //t.Show_Enumeration(); // using enumeration
                    }
                    /*case 2:
                    {
                        for(Studentinfo obj : teacharinfo.arr)
                        {
                            t.showStudent(obj);
                        }
                    }*/
                    break;
                    case 3:
                    {
                        int index,cc;
                        System.out.println("Enter your choice : ");
                        System.out.println("1.Search by roll no."+System.lineSeparator()+"2.Search by Name");
                        cc=sc.nextInt();
                        if(cc==1)
                        {
                            System.out.println("Enter roll no. : ");
                            int temp=sc.nextInt();
                            index=t.search(temp);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            System.out.println("Enter name : ");
                            String temp=sc.next();
                            index=t.search(temp);
                        }

                        student obj=new student();
                        obj=arr.get(index);
                        t.showStudent(obj);
                    }
                    break;
                    case 4:
                    {
                        t.update();
                    }
                    break;
                    case 5:
                    {
                        t.delete();
                    }
                    break;
                    case 6:
                    {
                        System.out.println("Fail Student : ");
                        for(student obj:arr)
                        {
                            t.fail(obj);
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                    }

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {

    }
    ss.close();
    s.close();
    sc.close();

}
}
```

student class defination:-

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class student implements Serializable
{
/**
 * 
 */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public int roll;
    public String name;
    public int attendance;
    public float percent;
    public String pass;
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader( new 
InputStreamReader(System.in));
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);



public String toString()
{
    return "Student rollno : "+this.roll+System.lineSeparator()+"Student name : "+this.name+System.lineSeparator()+"Student Percentage : "+this.percent+System.lineSeparator()+"Student Attendance : "+this.attendance;
}
}
```

Comment: Is your `StudentInfo` class implements `Serializable` interface? Do you see any exceptions?

Comment: yes my StudentInfo class also implements Serializable and there is no exceptions

Comment: Did you debug?  It might actually be blocked waiting for input on this line: `stud.pass=br.readLine();`.

Comment: yes i have .. i tried many ways to do it.. but program get terminated at writeObject().   i also provided drive link of my full project .. please check it

Comment: It is suspicious that the client wraps the socket's output stream in two different streams.  I strongly recommend avoiding this.  Choose *one* -- for your purposes, probably `ObjectOutputStream`.  The server, of course, has the flip side of the same issue, and any change in the client needs to be mirrored on the server.

Comment: before passing object I also want to send choice that's why is used to output stream... I know I tried to pass object first to check whether it is working or not

Comment: In any case, it seems unlikely that the client terminates abruptly without throwing an exception.  If that did happen, then it would signal a bug in the JVM.

Comment: @VikramVaishnav, you can send whatever data you want over the `ObjectOutputStream`.  You do not need a separate handle on the same underlying stream, and it is unwise to create or use one.

Comment: @JohnBollinger i update my code but still not working..